# Send arguments to Pytest fixture for Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

***Update1:***

Thank you for your answer.
It almost solves the problem. If I could be more precise:

How to instantiate the two drivers in 'init_pages', instead of creating two same methods for each driver?

The new snippet as you suggested:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
class BaseTestFF:

     @pytest.fixture
     def init_data(self, driver_init):
          self.web_driver = driver_init('firefox') #how to inject data via external commands? jenkins?
          self.web_driver2 = driver_init('chrome')


     @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
     @pytest.mark.usefixtures('init_data')
     def init_pages(self, init_data):
       #how to instanciate the two drivers here? istead of creating two same methods for each driver
       self.login_page = LoginPage(self.web_driver)
       self.application_page = ApplicationPage(self.web_driver)
```

In my selenium project, I would like to be able to send arguments, instead of them to be fixed in the conftest file.

For each different method, I would like it to use different browsers for different things.

Is there any way to send arguments TO the fixture??

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities

@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=['chrome']) #i would like to send here dynamic fixtures.
def driver_init(request):
    if request.param == 'firefox':
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    elif request.param == 'edge':
        web_driver = webdriver.Edge()  # dk:needs to be added the path
    else:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument(
            r'user-data-dir=Users/dannyk/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default')
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield
    web_driver.close()


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
class BaseTest:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def init_pages(self):
        self.login_page = lambda driver_type=self.driver: LoginPage(driver_type)
        self.application_page = lambda driver_type=self.driver: ApplicationPage(driver_type)   



class TestT4(BaseTest):

    # @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)   #here i would like to use firefox for the driver
    def test_init_firefox(self):
        self.getting_start_page.go_home_page()


    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)  #here i would like to use chrome for the driver
    def test_init_chrome(self):

        self.getting_start_page.go_home_page()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "factory as fixture" pattern in conftest, which is basically an inner function inside the fixture that accepts parameters. You can then pass them from your test as arguments.

In conftest:

```
@pytest.fixture
def driver_init():
   web_drivers = []

    def _driver_init(browser):
        if browser == 'firefox':
            web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            web_drivers.append(web_driver)
        elif browser == 'edge':
            web_driver = webdriver.Edge()  # dk:needs to be added the path
            web_drivers.append(web_driver)
        else:
            options = Options()
            options.add_argument(
            r'user-data-dir=Users/dannyk/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default')
            web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)    
            web_drivers.append(web_driver)
        return web_driver

    yield _driver_init

    for web_driver in web_drivers:
        web_driver.quit()
```

Then, in your test:

```
class TestT4(BaseTest):

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)   #here i would like to use firefox for the driver
    def test_init_firefox(self, driver_init):
        web_driver = driver_init("firefox")

    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)  #here i would like to use chrome for the driver
    def test_init_chrome(self, driver_init):
        web_driver = driver_init("chrome")
```

Or you can use the same concept on your `def_init_pages(self):` fixture to instantiate the pages and send the arguments from your tests.

Please check the [official documentation here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures).

---

#### Update

For your first new question:

> how to inject data via external commands? jenkins?

I believe what you're looking for is the `def pytest_addoption(parser)` fixture. It allows you to pass arguments to your test automation through the command line, when running Pytest. So you could pass the browser you want your tests to run with, locally or with Jenkins, with something like this:

In conftest:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

Then, on your `driver_init` fixture you wouldn't use the "factory as fixture" pattern:

```
@pytest.fixture
def driver_init(browser):
    if browser == 'firefox':
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    elif browser == 'edge':
        web_driver = webdriver.Edge()  # dk:needs to be added the path
    else:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument(
        r'user-data-dir=Users/dannyk/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default')
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)    
    yield web_driver
    web_driver.quit()
```

Then, to run your tests, you would pass the browser as argument:

`pytest --browser=firefox`

Please check these documents:

[Pass different values to a test function, depending on command line options](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options)
[pytest_addoption(parser: Parser, pluginmanager: PytestPluginManager) → None](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption)

For your second new question:

> how to instanciate the two drivers here? istead of creating two same methods for each driver

I think what might be the answer is the fixture parametrization that you used on your original question, but then with the `driver_init` fixture I suggested earlier (you wouldn't need the `def init_data(self, driver_init):` fixture you wrote):

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, params=["firefox", "chrome", "edge"])
def init_pages(self, request, driver_init):
   self.login_page = LoginPage(driver_init(request.param))
   self.application_page = ApplicationPage(driver_init(request.param))
```

Please note that I have removed the `@pytest.mark.usefixtures` as it has no effect when applied to another fixture. You need to declare what fixture you're using as a parameter:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def init_pages(self, init_data):
```

Please check the `pytest.mark.usefixtures` [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=usefixtures#pytest-mark-usefixtures)

I hope this gives you more tools to figure out what you need to do to sort your problem. I'm not sure if I understand completely what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have updated my question 'update1' in the beginning of the article with updated snipped code as you suggested:
how to instantiate the two drivers in 'init_pages'? instead of creating two same methods for each driver?